# Search for a string in a Worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search for a particular string "ERROR" in all the worksheets in the workbook and make it bold and color the found cell red.

I am able to parse through each worksheet. I am not able to use the `Find` function of VBA.

Comment: Yes Record a macro and manually search using CTL F. See what code do you get?

Comment: Thanks a lot. However the contents of the cell is a formula and not text. So, I search by "Look in Values". But I am not able to make it Bold and make the cell as Red. Any Idea ?

Comment: Yes you have to search using "Look in Values" and also you have to select "Workbook" in the `Within` dropdown. Then with the found cell make it bold and Red. See this link http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Why do you not just use conditional formatting ? That serms to be the obvious answer.

Comment: If you have a formula like `=IF(B1=C1,"Success","ERROR")` then use `xlFormulas` like Chris mentioned if you want to check of the sting in a formula. However if you are only concerned with the formula's output which results in "ERROR" (If B1<>C1 in above example) then use  `xlValues`. Another Scenatio: if you have `=0/0` which gives you `#DIV/0!` then use `xlValues` when searching for `#DIV/0!`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an example of using `Find` and formatting the found cells

```
Sub FindERROR()
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    ' Set Search value
    SearchString = "ERROR"
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    ' loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
            After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            ' if found, remember location
            FirstFound = cl.Address
            ' format found cell
            Do
                cl.Font.Bold = True
                cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                ' find next instance
                Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
                ' repeat until back where we started
            Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 I added a small clarification in my comment in OP's thread.

Comment: @chris neilsen - How can I get the Values that are in the row where my string is found?

Answer (score 1):

if you are searching in excel vba you can use following simple code with ***InStr*** command.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RowNum As Long

RowNum = 1


Do Until Sheets("Data").Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = ""

If InStr(1, Sheets("Data").Cells(RowNum, 2).Value, TextBox1.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
On erro GoTo next1
ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("Data").Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheets("Data").Cells(RowNum, 2).Value
End If
next1:
RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

[you can download example file from here](http://excelhub.org/excel-vba-to-display-search-result-in-listbox/)

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
If Not WorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z150").Find("Cookie") Is Nothing 
    MsgBox "Found a Cookie"
End If
```