# COBOL analysis using Excel sheet. Need script to locate paragraphs

Tags: excel, cobol, vba

I have copied a COBOL program in to Excel sheet. I want write a macro and assign keys. So when I press the assigned keys it should do the following thing. For example, when the cursor is at the row `PERFORM 001-PARA-ADD` it should store the row value (line no 2) in a variable and copy only para name `001-PARA-ADD` and add `.` at the end of the string and strip out the other characters in the line and search for string `001-PARA-ADD.` and move the control to the line 7 where the string `001-PARA-ADD.` is present and when I press the keys again it should comeback to the initial location line 2.

Please tell me if it possible. Please let me know if more details need about the requirement.

```
 IF A > B
345    PERFORM 001-PARA-ADD 12345
     IF A < B
        PERFORM 002-PARA-SUB
     END-IF
    END-IF
    001-PARA-ADD.
       COMPUTE A = A+B.
    .
    002-PARA-SUB.
       COMPUTE B = B-A.
    .
```

Image of the program:

[image: image of the program]

Comment: Yes it is possible. But please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, therefore you will need to show what you have already tried ([edit] your question and add your code) and ask a *specific* question to your code. Including any error messages and where they occur in your code and where you get stuck.

Comment: you always want to search based on cursor position? and only once?

Comment: So you're only looking for paragraphs and plan to ignore sections?

Comment: @Peh I don't know much of Vba. I tried recording a macro but it did not work at all.

Comment: @Myplanet That's ok but you cannot expect anyone writing the code for you. People usually are here to help *you to solve the issue yourself* and not to solve the issue *for you*.

Comment: @GowthamShiva yes always based on cursor position. If we can search more than one level It would be great.

Comment: @cschneid yes, locating the paragraph will be enough for basic analysis

Comment: @peh thanks for the response. I will try to write it myself.

Comment: @Myplanet have a look at the answer below. You will find most of what you need there. If you run into issues [edit] your question, post your actual code and tell where you got stuck to get more help from people here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect dots with these:

I have copied a COBOL program in to Excel sheet. I want write a macro and assign keys. So when I press the assigned keys it should do the following thing. For example, when the cursor is at the row PERFORM 001-PARA-ADD it should store the row value (line no 2) in a variable

```
   strValue = ActiveCell.Value
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = ActiveCell.Address 'save your cell address into a scratch sheet
```

and copy only para name  001-PARA-ADD

```
   arrayValue = Split(strValue, " ")
   For Each val In arrayValue
        If Instr(val, "PARA") > 0 Then
            strPara = val
            Goto ProcessNext
        End If
   Next

   ProcessNext:
```

and add . at the end of the string

```
   strPara = strPara & "."
```

and strip out the other characters in the line

```
   strPara = Trim(strPara)
```

and search for string 001-PARA-ADD. and move the control to the line 7 where the string 001-PARA-ADD. is present

```
get the code from this link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813720/search-a-string-in-a-worksheet-in-vba>!
```

and when I press the keys again it should comeback to the initial location line 2.

```
   'create another macro for this
   ActiveSheet.Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value).Activate
```